# 500 Internal Server Error on PHP Site on Page that DOESN'T exists

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Looking into my search console I found out some server's errors. For my surprise, I'm getting the 500 internal server error in a subdirectory that doesn't exists. BUT I have a 404 redirection that you get it on any other subdir or page that doesn't exists. Maybe that subdir of the site used to exists a few months ago but I don't see it in my server anymore. I check the .htaccess and I have all simple:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://fryla.com.ar/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.fryla.com.ar/404
```

For example, I get the error on:
https://www.fryla.com.ar/portfolio/anything
but not in:
https://www.fryla.com.ar/anyotherdir/something
https://www.fryla.com.ar/anyotherdir/

EDIT:
I follow the advice to look into the log (I don't have access buy my hosting provide me with the log). The error is:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable 
configuration error. Use \'LimitInternalRecursion\' to increase the limit if 
necessary. Use \'LogLevel debug\' to get a backtrace.
```

But like I said, I don't have any redirect in my htaccess. Any ideas?

Tks in advance!!!

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Checkout your server logs because you could have just setup a wrong .htaccess rewriting

Comment: where can i find the server log? Sorry but it's not in my public_html dir. Maybe I have to enable it someway? Tks

Comment: Does it work if you change your rule from `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php` I added an optional traling  slash to your pattern.

Comment: It works but it doesn't solve my issue at all. I'm getting the 500 error page still in the same page.

Comment: Do you have another htaccess file in `/portfolio` ?

Comment: No, I don't have any other htaccess file. And the dir "/portfolio/" it doesn't exist.

Comment: I add an edit with the log detail. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `ErrorDocument 404 https://www.fryla.com.ar/404` to just the location `ErrorDocument 404 /404`. removed an extra `RewriteEngine On` as only 1 is needed

copy the following:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://fryla.com.ar/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

EDIT: update to error document location

Comment: That code just broke the entire site, the line "ErrorDocument 404/404" was the issue...

Comment: @Fryla-CristianMarucci where is the location to the 404.html page ? edit: updated location to include .html

Comment: I tried it but I don't think that it's the issue here. I used now only one RewriteEngine but the issue of the question is still happening. Tks anyway.

Comment: is this your 404 redirect ? `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://fryla.com.ar/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... this used to be my .htaccess for remove the php extensions of every page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Now, I found another code for doing it and the error is gone. The new code is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Tks to you all for the help!